# Geometric sequence (progression)

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $U_0=\frac{11}{4}\;; \quad \quad U_{n+1}= 3U_n-4\;; \quad \quad V_n=4U_n+b$

For what value(s) of $b$ do the $V_n$ form a geometric sequence?

Comment: Please [use MathJax for typesetting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020)

Comment: Can you find the geometric sequence for $U_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: There are several ways to go about solving the problem. One is to solve the recurrence for the numbers $U_n$ to get a closed form for them, then use that to get a closed form for $V_n$ involving $b$, and finally solve for $b$ on the assumption that the sequence $V_n$ form a geometric sequence. Since you didn’t use a discrete mathematics tag, however, you may not have the tools to do that.

Another is to write to observe that if $U_{n+1}=3U_n-4$ and $V_n=4U_n+b$, then $4U_n=V_n-b$, and

$$\begin{align*}
V_{n+1}&=4U_{n+1}+b\\
&=4(3U_n-4)+b\\
&=3\cdot4U_n-16+b\\
&=3(V_n-b)-16+b\\
&=3V_n-16-2b\;,
\end{align*}$$

and at this point it’s quite straightforward to figure out what $b$ must be in order for the $V_n$ to form a geometric sequence.

Yet another way is to calculate $V_0,V_1$, and $V_2$. Clearly $V_0=11+b$. $U_1=\frac{17}4$, so $V_1=17+b$. And $U_2=\frac{35}4$, so $V_2=35+b$. If the $V_n$ are to form a geometric sequence, the ratios $\frac{V_1}{V_0}$ and $\frac{V_2}{V_1}$ must be equal. Setting them equal and solving for $b$ then gives you the only possible value for $b$. Unlike the first two approaches, however, it this does not prove that this value of $b$ actually *does* work: it just shows that it’s the only one that could possibly work. To show that it really does work, you’ll end up doing something more or less like the calculation in my second approach, but with a known value of $b$, to verify that the $V_n$ do increase geometrically.

Answer (score 0):

We have $v_{n+1}= 3v_n -2b-16 $. Then, for $b=-8$, $(v_n)_n$ is a geometric sequence.

Answer (score 0):

First solve the recurrence.

$$U_n = 3U_{n-1}-4 \\=3^2U_{n-2} - 4(3^1 + 3^0) \\= ... = 3^nU_0 -4(3^{n-1} + 3^{n-2} + ... + 3^0)$$

Simplify that expression using the formula for the sum of a geometric series. After further simplification and using the given $U_0$, you get:

$$U_n = \frac 14\cdot 3^{n+1}+2$$

(you should prove that by induction, a quick step)

So $\displaystyle V_n = 3^{n+1} + 8 + b$

Clearly, $b=-8$ to cancel out the constant and leave a pure geometric progression.